# distance from a point to a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have an n-dimensional hyperplane: $w'x + b = 0$ and a point $x_0$. The shortest distance from this point to a hyperplane is $d = \frac{|w \cdot x_0+ b|}{||w||}$. I have no problem to prove this for 2 and 3 dimension space using algebraic manipulations, but fail to do this for an n-dimensional space. Can someone show a nice explanation for it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem. In principal one can use Lagrange multipliers and solve a large system of equations, but my attempt to do so met with a road block. However, since you are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have the privilege of orthogonal projection via the dot product. To this end we need to construct a vector from the plane to $x_0$ to project onto a vector perpendicular to the plane. Then we compute the *length of the projection* to determine the distance from the plane to the point.

First, you have an affine hyperplane defined by $w \cdot x + b=0$ and a point $x_0$. Suppose that $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a point satisfying $w \cdot X+b=0$, i.e. it is a point on the plane. You should construct the vector $x_0 - X$ which points from $X$ to $x_0$ so that you can project it onto the unique vector *perpendicular* to the plane. Some quick reasoning should tell you that this vector is, in fact, $w$. So we want to compute $\| \text{proj}_{w} (x_0-X)\|$. Some handy formulas give us
$$ d=\| \text{proj}_{w} (x_0-X)\| = \left\| \frac{(x_0-X)\cdot w}{w \cdot w} w \right\| = |x_0 \cdot w - X \cdot w|\frac{\|w\|}{\|w\|^2} = \frac{|x_0 \cdot w - X \cdot w|}{\|w\|}$$
We chose $X$ such that $w\cdot X=-b$ so we get
$$ d=\| \text{proj}_{w} (x_0-X)\| = \frac{|x_0 \cdot w +b|}{\|w\|} $$
as desired.

This almost seems like cheating and purely heuristic based on Euclidean geometry. Indeed, I would be more satisfied with a solution via Lagrange multipliers since it would not have required the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has an inner product and just needed the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead. But we have the inner product, so maybe geometry will suffice for us this time.

To make this argument more concrete you should do each step in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for a line $y=mx+b$ and a point $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Can you please clarify how from $ \left\| \frac{(x_0-X)\cdot w}{w \cdot w} w \right\|$ you ended up with $|x_0 \cdot w - X \cdot w|\frac{\|w\|}{\|w\|^2}$? In fact I am interested how $w$ became $||w||$.

Comment: The dot product of two vectors is a real number. For any scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ it is true that $\| \lambda w \| = |\lambda| \| w \|$. You can verify this via the definition of the norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is $\|w\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i^2}$.

Comment: oh, sorry, I have missed that the whole expression is in $|| ... ||$. Now everything is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. Could you please help me solve the similar question which is in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296319/find-the-shortest-distance-of-a-point-to-the-solution-set-of-a-linear-equation) but with matrix form? @Yeldarbskich

Comment: There is no unique vector perpendicular to the plane. The span of the vector is unique though.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a Lagrange multiplier based solution.

The goal is to minimize $ (x_0 - x)'(x_0 - x) $ subject to $ w'x + b = 0 $

The Lagrangian is $ (x_0 - x)'(x_0 - x) - L(w'x + b) $

The derivative of the Lagrangian is $ -2(x_0 - x) - Lw = 0 $

Dot with $ w $, we get $ -2w'(x_0 - x) - Lw'w = 0 \implies L = -\frac{2w'(x_0 - x)}{w'w} $

Dot with $ (x_0 - x) $, we get
\begin{alignat*}{1}
& -2(x_0 - x)'(x_0 - x) - L(x_0 - x)'w = 0 \\
& \implies -2(x_0 - x)'(x_0 - x) = -\frac{2w'(x_0 - x)}{w'w} (x_0 - x)'w  \\ & \implies (x_0 - x)'(x_0 - x) = \frac{\left(w'(x_0 - x)\right)^2}{w'w} \\& \implies (x_0 - x)'(x_0 - x) = \frac{\left(w'x_0 + b\right)^2}{w'w} 
\end{alignat*}

Taking square root gives the answer we wanted.

Comment: A solution based of Lagrange multiplier - Yeldarbskich

Comment: Is there something that led you to dot with $w$ and $(x_0-x)$ other than that it happens to work out?

Comment: The problem with solving these vector equations is that you can't move the 'factor' to the other side if it is not a scalar. We can remedy that by computing the dot product with itself. After doing so, it turns scalar, and then we can move it. That's the idea anyway.

Answer (score 14):

The problem has a simple solution via elementary geometry. Indeed, consider the line via $x_0$ and parallel to the vector $w$, namely $L := \{x_0 + tw \mid t \in \mathbb R\} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$. This line cuts your hyperplane when $w^\top(x_0+tw) + b = 0$, i.e $t = -(w^\top x_0 + b)/\|w\|^2$. The distance between this point of intersection and starting point $x_0$ is
$$
d := \|x_0 + tw - x_0\| = \|tw\|=|t|\|w\| = \frac{|w^\top x_0+b|}{\|w\|^2}\cdot\|w\| = \frac{|w^\top x_0 + b|}{\|w\|},
$$
as claimed.